# Block suggested edit if the edit summary contains an email address

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, spam

A follow-up from [this question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7733/improve-filtering-of-spam-suggested-edits).

I've noticed that many spam suggested edits have edit summaries that contain an email address (examples: [[1]](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/205950) [[2]](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/310396) [[3]](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/301861) [[4]](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/305070) [[5]](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/305846)). Spambots seem to be treating the edit summary field as if it were the email field in a blog post comment form. It would be great if we took advantage of this to block these spam suggested edits.

Comment: Or, blocking BBCode links (`[url]` style) and HTML link (`<a>` style)?

Comment: Sounds good. Just don't block raw http:// links. I link to a lot of meta questions for 'this cleanup' or 'that discussion' etc